# Tkinter capturing location of two different buttons in Button1 click and release

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter

I have a grid of buttons in an 8x12 grid. Eventually, I want to be able to color a section (like a top left 3x3 grid) a specific color. For now, I have this question. Is it possible to get one button widget using `button.bind("<Button-1>", myfunc2)` and then get a second button widget using `button.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", myfunc2)`? An outline of the code I have right now is below

```
class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, main):
        self.button_frame = tk.Frame(main)
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
        self.button_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.grid = tk.Frame(self.button_frame)
        self.grid.grid(sticky='nsew', column=0, row=7, columnspan=2)
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self.button_frame, 7, weight=1)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self.button_frame, 0, weight=1)

        self.button_list = {}

        self.createbuttongrid()


    def createbuttongrid(self):
        label = 1
        for row in range(8):
            for column in range(12):
                button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text='Well %s' % label)
                button.bind("<Button-1>", self.buttonclick)  # this line is in question
                button.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.buttonrelease)  # along with this line
                button.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky='nsew')
                self.button_list[button] = (row, column)
                label += 1


    def buttonclick(self, event):
        first_button = event.widget
        print(self.button_list[first_button])


    def buttonrelease(self, event):
        second_button = event.widget
        print(self.button_list[second_button])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import tkinter as tk

    root = tk.Tk()
    MyApp(main=root)
    root.mainloop()
```

(The resizing (with the above example) doesn't work perfectly, but that's not important for now.)

Currently, when I run this and click on the top left button, I get (0, 0), and when I release I also get (0, 0). I think this is because the same widget is being passed into `def buttonclick` and `def buttonrelease`, but I'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<ButtonRelease>` event will return the same widget that caught the `<ButtonPress>` event. That is due to the fact that clicking on a button causes the button to do a *grab*, which means all events are sent to the button rather than to any other button.

You can use the universal widget method `winfo_containing` to determine the widget at a given x/y coordinate. You must give it an x and y coordinate relative to the root window, which is conveniently supplied by the `event` object passed to an event handler.

```
def buttonrelease(event):
    second_button = event.widget.winfo_containing(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    ...
```